# eee900 Keyboard Issues

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, keyboard, eeepc

My girlfriend has an ASUS eee900 (the version with the 2 SSDs). Although it ships with Xandros, one of the first things I did for her was remove it and install Ubuntu. She's had Ubuntu Netbook Remix on there for a while, but once Unity was enforced on everyone, the poor little netbook can't cope with it (the graphics performance is pretty hopeless).

After swapping and changing a few times to get something she likes, I've installed Linux Mint 9. Unfortunately, the keyboard isn't mapped correctly and I can't find the correct driver to use for it. This means that some of the keys only work with the left shift key, some others only with the right shift key, and some others work with neither. In particular, she can't type an @ sign - which makes emailing people difficult!

Any advice on how I can get the keyboard operating again would be very much appreciated by both of us!

Comment: Did the keybord work correctly whilst Ubuntu was installed?

Comment: Have you tried installing the 10.04 netbook edition again? That really might be the best short term fix until graphics performance of Unity is improved.

Comment: The keyboard was working fine during installation - I believed the problems were sorted because of that! But once it rebooted after installation, no such luck. I haven't tried reinstalling the old version again yet, but if I have to, I will.

Comment: Linux Mint questions should go on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Jorge - thanks, but I believed that since Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu that qualified it for appearing here, particular as the problem also occurred on a stock UNR installation. It would appear to be an issue with the keyboard mappings shipped with the current releases. I am going to downgrade to UNR 10.04 to see if that solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to switch to the regular graphic interface on the netbook remixed edition of Ubuntu, by selecting the proper environment at the login time. If you are setup for an automatic login, you can still logout and re-login with the proper credentials. The selection is done through some of the icons on the bottom of the desktop BEFORE logging in. This is how I got rid of the Unity environment, which is also giving me hard time on my Eee900 netbook.

Because of performance, I now use Jolicloud on my netbook. It is much faster, although the environment is not what I would personally prefer. But id does a better job than Ubuntu.

I realize it might not answer your original question, but it may solve the keyboard issue you had with Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried my girlfriend on Jolicloud - she hated it! I think the best plan is for me to downgrade to 10.04 or earlier, to see if that fixes it. Thank you anyway!